# How do I continuously check the status of a process and execute something once the process stops with an Apple Script?

Tags: macos, applescript, script

I'm using an Apple Script to open an application and transcode a file.  What I need to be able to do is continuously check the CPU usage of the process and when the CPU usage hits 0 I need to do something else.  Below is what I'm using the get the CPU usage of the process (GoPro Player).  Anyone have a suggestion?

```
getProcessPercentCPU("GoPro Player")

on getProcessPercentCPU(someProcess)
    do shell script "/bin/ps -xco %cpu,command | /usr/bin/awk '/" & someProcess & "$/ {print $1}'"
    set GoProUsage to (do shell script "/bin/ps -xco %cpu,command | /usr/bin/awk '/" & someProcess & "$/ {print $1}'") as integer
end getProcessPercentCPU
```

Comment: Can't you get the app to post a Notification?

Comment: You should be able to just use an `idle` handler in a stay-open application - see the AppleScript Language Guide section [About Handlers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW7).

Comment: Tetsujin, the app does post a notification.  Do you know how I would get that notificaition to trigger another action?  I don't have any programming experience.